# Collapse and enlarge views using threads in android

Tags: android, multithreading, animation, view

What I wish to do is:
On a screen have lets say three layouts WHICH ARE INITIALLY MINIMIZED. And when I click on any one of them, the one that is clicked is enlarged and the remaining two collapse but are still visible. How can this be achieved  using threads  and the Animation class? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a Handler to modify the UI from a not UI thread.

Yo have to create a Handler in the activity:

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
```

Then, your thread has to be something like:

```
Thread th = new Thread(){
   public void run(){
       //your non UI interaction code
       handler.post( new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                 //your UI interaction code
            }
       });
   }
};
th.start();
```

Any way, I think it is more elegant to use an AsyncTask for this actions.

Regards.